# Работа с MSSQL и Firebird

Tags: delphi

Всем, Доброе время суток.
 У меня возникла такая проблема. (Может она многим покажется простой, не судите строга. Ведь все учились).
  Я с MSSQL 2012 сделал выборку по 5 - ти таблицам. И передал полученный результат своей формы в  DBGRID. 
  И мне нужно сохранить этот результат в собственной базе Firebird.
  Подскажите (небольшой пример) как это сделать. Или где почитать про это. Или есть проще решения.

Благодарю заранее всех кто откликнулся на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам просто надо вставить данные из `mssql` в `firebird`, то лучше всего настроить сервер `firebird` как связанный (`linked server`) на `mssql`. И вставлять/запрашивать данные между серверами обычными запросами.